# Tcl string saved in variable and text file is different

Tags: variables, tcl, text-files, string-comparison

I have a Tcl script which gets a string back as an answer and saves it in the variable $Data. This string is saved in a txt file later. If I open the file to copy the string and compare it to the original string saved in Data it is not the same. I don't understand why it is different?

```
proc SendFile { FileName {Channel {}} } {

    if { $Channel == {} } { set Channel [GetCurrentChannel] }

    lassign [EncodeFile $FileName] Type Data
    

    Send $Channel FILE [file tail $FileName]
    Send $Channel $Type $Data
    Send $Channel FILE {}
    set fp [open "log.txt" w+]
    puts $fp $Data
    close $fp
    
    set fp [open "log.txt" r]
    set ant [read $fp]

    if {$Data == $ant} {
        puts "success"
    }
    
}
```

Comment: From the duplicate: using `puts -nonewline $fp $X` avoids a newline being written at the end of the string (with the newline the comparison is false).

Comment: Or, `read -nonewline $fp`